# Custom messages and placeholder text in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Here is some script extracts:

```pascal
MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallFailed,Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallFailed,Visual Studio x64 Redistributable}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallFailed,Visual Studio x86 Redistributable}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
```

The custom message is defined like this:

```
English.InstallFailed=The installation of %s failed. The Meeting Schedule Assistant installation will be aborted.
```

Yet, a user has just reported:

[image]

Why is the placeholder still showing `%s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`[CustomMessages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=custommessagessection) uses `%1`...`%9` for arguments:

> Messages may take arguments, from %1 up to %9. You can rearrange the order of the arguments (i.e. move the %2 before a %1) and also duplicate arguments if needed (i.e. "%1 ... %1 %2"). On messages with arguments, use two consecutive "%" characters to embed a single "%". "%n" creates a line break.